# Assign different set of colors to trend lines with varying timeframes using input.timeframe and request.security with a custom function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to assign a set of colors (BuyColor and SellColor) to two trend lines on two different time frames, so 4 colors total.

The input.timeframe and custom function all limit the ways I know how to assign colors with conditional formatting. This seems simple enough in my head but I have come up short of ideas..

```
//Code: 

res = input.timeframe(title='Trend 1', defval="")
res2 = input.timeframe(title='Trend 2', defval="15")

buyColor = color.green
sellColor = color.red
//buyColor2 for Trend2
//SellColor2 for Trend2

Function() =>
    var int trend = 0
    var float up = 0.0
    var float down = 0.0
// lots of redacted calcs from custom function here for simplification 
    htColor = trend == 0 ? buyColor : sellColor   
    ht = trend == 0 ? up : down
    [ht, htColor]

[ht2, htColor2] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res, Function())
[ht3, htColor3] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, res2, Function())

plot(ht2, color=htColor2, title="Trend 1", linewidth=2)
plot(ht3, color=htColor3, title="Trend 2", linewidth=2)

//END OF CODE
```

PS: I have had every error possible and I am lacking some wisdom! I need an intelligent hero! I hope this question is helpful to others in the community as I have so far struggled to find an answer online myself (I am fairly new to PineScript). Thank you in advance!

**Update:**

I wrote comments below in response to answer provided and posted further code as I attempted (unsuccesfully) a few different ideas.. I also changed "" to "5" to clarify that I want the option of different time frame to chart. Perhaps the below code will resonate with someone enough to guide me to the end goal..

```
timeFrame1  = "5"
timeFrame2  = "15"

res         = input.timeframe(title='Trend 1', defval=timeFrame1)
res2        = input.timeframe(title='Trend 2', defval=timeFrame2)

trend1TF    = str.tonumber(timeFrame1)
trend2TF    = str.tonumber(timeFrame2)

buyColor   = color(na)
sellColor  = color(na)

if trend1TF == 5
    buyColor := color.aqua 
else
    color(na)
if trend2TF == 15
    buyColor := color.blue 
else
    color(na)

if trend1TF == 5
    sellColor := color.orange
else
    color(na)
if trend2TF == 15
    sellColor := color.red
else
    color(na)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to got everything just right with the ternary operators regarding the color assignment. It's how you do it.
No errors, whatsoever. Also great.
The problem I see here lies in the simplicity of your example, meaning you'll always be plotting zeroes only and get only "buyColor".
The way you built your structure up can work, however the key point is (in this example at least I don't know about your code) that in your calculations nothing happens and you should probably use some ohlc/volume etc. values from the imported security otherwise the import makes little sense.
Furthermore if your timeframe is "" (empty string), you're working on your chart timeframe directly so you don't need a request for that.
Useful [tradingview api](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity) and [docs](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Timeframes.html?highlight=request%20security)

**Update after further clarification:**
Without seeing the entire script I can only try to provide you some help. Here is a simplified working version of your color conditionals in your update:

```
buyColor = if trend1TF == 5
    color.aqua 
else if trend2TF == 15
    color.blue
else
    color(na)

sellColor = if trend1TF == 5
    color.orange
else if trend2TF == 15
    color.red
else
    color(na)
```

The limitation by this is that the focus is on the colors meaning trend1 and 2 cannot work simultaneously.
With this you could use as many trends as you want:

```
getBuyColorForTrend(trend) =>
    if trend == 5
        color.aqua
    else if trend == 15
        color.blue
    // ... +n trends here
    else
        color(na)

getSellColorForTrend(trend) =>
    if trend == 5
        color.orange
    else if trend == 15
        color.red
    // ... +n trends here
    else
        color(na)
```

You have plenty of options. You could also use `switch` instead of `if else if` if you like. It really depends on what you need.

Comment: Many thanks for your response! :)
A few added comments: I purposely removed some of the complex calculations inside the custom function for simplification purposes (also I am not the original author) but the calcs do return both "buyColor" and "sellColor" with the help of plenty more variables which I removed.
I did find a partial solution which was to copy and paste the code twice, one section for the current time frame with a pair of colors without the need for request.security nor input.timeframe. The second pasted section would use the OP custom function with a different set of colors.

Comment: The problem with the above comment is that it limits the indicator to current time + one other time frame. It also duplicates the code whereas I was aiming for one custom function with 2 outputs and varying color schemes. I also wanted best practice and refined/polished finish. I really appreciate your time, its nice to get feedback from community members with experience!

Comment: Alright, I provided an update in my answer to your update. That's all I could do without seeing your code. Either way, I hope I could still help you with my perspective and wish you good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your expertise, I'll do my best to find a working solution and post results! To be honest, posting the full 100 lines of code seemed lazy to me but appreciate context would help answer questions. This is my first post so very new to the platform. You have been very kind, all the best!